# How to sum variables in groups by condition with ave()?

Tags: r

I'm really getting into `ave()` tonight. In a grouped data frame I want a variable with the sum of the values in control condition `d==0` for each group. Rows with `d==1` should get the value for `d==0` as well. If the group doesn't contain any `d==0` it should produce `NA`.

```
set.seed(26)
n <- 100
df1 <- data.frame(d=rbinom(n, 1, .5),
                  group=rbinom(n, 5, .5),
                  val=rnorm(n, 1000, 100))
> head(df1, 3)
  d group       val
1 0     3  955.9525
2 0     1 1089.0666
3 1     2  993.6181
```

This `ave()` function produces the right values, but all the `d==1` are left out.

```
df1$n0 <- with(df1, ave(val[d == 0], group, FUN=sum))
```

With this `ifelse()` I also can't get the right thing.

```
with(df1, ifelse(d==0,
                 ave(val[d==0], group, FUN=sum),
                 NA))
```

I want something like this

```
    d group  val    n0
1   0     1  955   955
3   1     1  993   955
4   1     2  949  1895
5   0     2  954  1895
6   0     2  941  1895
...
```

How could I include the `d==1` condition, so that they receive the `d==0` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, some arithmetic works:

```
df1$n0 <- with(df1, ave(val*(d==0), group, FUN=sum))
```