# Group_by, conditional sum and replace the variables in R

Tags: r, replace, group-by, conditional-statements, stata

I would like to convert these two lines from Stata into R code:

```
bysort  sj hid: generate H = sum( d ) if f == 1 & ( d == 1 | d == 2 ) 
bysort  sj hid: replace  H = H[ _N ]  if f == 1 & ( d == 1 | d == 2 )
```

I used

```
H = ifelse(f==1 & (d==1 | d==2), ave(d,sj,hid, FUN = sum),0),
```

However, I got this as a result:

| sj | hid | f | d | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 27 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2000 | 60 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 302 | 1 | 1 | 6 |
| 2000 | 302 | 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 2000 | 302 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

I'm wondering how I can change my code in R to get H=3 instead of 6 in hid 302.

Comment: FWIW, a Stata one-liner is `bysort sj hid : egen H = total(cond(f == 1 & (d == 1 | d == 2), d, 0))` where `cond()` is equivalent to `ifelse()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a code translation site. However try something along the lines of `library(tidyverse); test_H %>% mutate(H = case_when(f == 1 & d %in% c(1,2) ~  H[n()], TRUE ~ H))`. Mutate is used to transform columns when using tidyverse, and case_when is basically a "if else" in tidyverse terms. Alternatively `test_H %>% group_by(sj, hid) %>% mutate(H = case_when(f == 1 & d %in% c(1, 2) ~ last(H), TRUE ~ H)` if we need gropuing by the `sj` and `hid` columns (also showcasing the `last` function).

Comment: I don't understand the need of the first line in your stata code. look, I'm no R expert so I don't know any one liners but I think you can achieve this by creating a dataframe with the calculation at `sj` & `hid` level (`group_by()`), and then join that result to the source dataframe. The second line in the stata code is basically counting `d`.

Comment: `sum()` in Stata yields cumulative or running sum, so the original Stata code calculates such cumulative sums for different groups and then looks in the last observation of each group to see each overall sum or total. As commented earlier, you don't have to do it that way.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for your contributions! I understand it in the same way. But what stumbles me is in stata if H calculates the sum with only d=1 or 2, or including d=3 (first table or second table)?

Comment: Leave the `if` qualifier off your `replace` statement.

Comment: @samkart 
The first line helps me to get only sum of d, only if d=1 or d=2 and f=1, for other d, H is 0. So I think the first line only gives the result 1,2,or 3.  The second line counts how many H in the group are non-zero. Because later I'm interested in how many H=3 I have, there are 2 steps here.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks. I tried using ```test_H %>% group_by(sj, hid) %>% mutate(H = case_when(f == 1 & d %in% c(1, 2) ~ last(H), TRUE ~ H)```, however, if there is d !=1 or 2 in the household (group by hid), the sum of d will all be 0 for all d, which is a bit off from what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers above. I just found this very helpful.

[How to sum variables in groups by condition with ave()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204494/how-to-sum-variables-in-groups-by-condition-with-ave)

And it gives me the result I want now.

`H=ifelse(f==1 & (d==1|d==2),ave(d*(d==1|d==2),sj,hid,FUN = sum),0)`